# Shell Scripting removing text before and after strings

Tags: shell, scripting, sed, awk

I need to shell script a way to get the random unknown junk text out of a text file. I am stuck on how to do this because i don't know what the junk text will say.  Basically i need to remove everything before, after, and in between the pieces.  I want to keep the text that is inside the pieces.

```
--Begin file


random unknown junk text

----Begin Piece one ---- 
random important text
----End Piece one ----

random unknown junk text

----Begin Piece two ---- 
random important text
----End Piece two ----

random unknown junk text

----Begin Piece two ---- 
random important text
----End Piece two ----

random unknown junk text


end of file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n '/^\(--Begin file\|end of file\)/{p;b}; /^----Begin Piece/{p;:a;n;/^----End Piece/{p;b};p;ba}' inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `/^\(--Begin file\|end of file\)/{p;b}` - Print the file beginning/ending lines (matches literal text)
- `/^----Begin Piece/{` - If the line matches the block begin marker

  - `p` - Print it
  - `:a` - label a
  - `n` - Read the next line
  - `/^----End Piece/{` - If it's the block end marker

    - `p` - Print it
    - `b` - Branch to the end to read the next line of input
  - `}` - end if
  - `p` - Print a line that's within the block
  - `ba` - Branch to label a to see if there are more lines in the block
- `}` - end if

Comment: @Matt: `sed -n -i ...` (with some versions of `sed` the backup extension argument to `-i` is mandatory: `sed -n -i .bak ...`). You can also do `sed ... inputfile > temp && mv temp inputfile`.

Comment: Awesome that works, thanks for your help.  This is the first time i ever had to use sed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3< file.txt
fl=0
regex='----Begin Piece.+'
regexe='----End Piece.+'
while read <&3
do
    if [ $fl -eq 1 ] && [[ ! "$REPLY" =~ $regexe ]]; then
        echo "$REPLY"
    fi
    if [[ "$REPLY" =~ $regex ]]; then fl=1; fi
    if [[ "$REPLY" =~ $regexe ]]; then fl=0; fi
done
exec 3>&-
```

Comment: If you quote the pattern on the right hand side of `=~` it ceases to be a regex and is taken literally.